# PDFsharp - Import PdfDocument Object; Concatenate Pages

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

So I have made this function that returns a `PdfPage` representing the object. I need a feature to call that function from a number of objects with that function and combine it all into a `PdfDocument`.

Here is the function:

```
public List<PdfPage> GetPdfPages(DateTime date) {
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();

    if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(Commons.PATH, "template.pdf")))
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Template not found");

    PdfDocument template = PdfReader.Open(Path.Combine(Commons.PATH, "template.pdf"), PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

    if (template.Pages.Count < 2)
        throw new FileLoadException("Template corrupted");

    for (int i = 0; i < template.PageCount; i++) pdf.AddPage(template.Pages[i]);

    XFont main = new XFont("Open Sans Light", 10, XFontStyle.Regular);
    XBrush brush = XBrushes.Black;

    foreach (PdfPage page in pdf.Pages) {

        XGraphics graph = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

        if (employee != null && employee.name != null) graph.DrawString(employee.name, main, brush, 58.5f, 93f);
        graph.DrawString(date.ToString("d MMMM yyyy", new CultureInfo("id")), main, brush, 58.5f, 78.25f);

        graph.DrawString(GetTotalDaysWorked().ToString(), main, brush, 134.65f, 113.5f);

        if (employee != null && GetPremi()) graph.DrawString(employee.premi.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("id")), main, brush, 211.25f, 113.5f);
        if (employee != null) graph.DrawString(GetPokok().ToString("C", new CultureInfo("id")), main, brush, 211.25f, 127.5f);

        for (int i = 0; i < days.Length; i++) {
            Day day = days[i];

            graph.DrawString(day.check_in.ToString("H.mm", new CultureInfo("id")), main, brush, 59.5f, 148.82f + (i * 14.173f));
            graph.DrawString(day.check_out.ToString("H.mm", new CultureInfo("id")), main, brush, 95.75f, 148.82f + (i * 14.173f));
            graph.DrawString(day.GetWorkDuration().ToString(new CultureInfo("id")), main, brush, 135.65f, 148.82f + (i * 14.173f));
        }

        graph.DrawString(prev_over.ToString(new CultureInfo("id")), main, brush, 135.65f, 248f);

        graph.DrawString(GetTotalHoursWorked().ToString(new CultureInfo("id")), main, brush, 135.65f, 264.85f);

        if (employee != null) graph.DrawString((GetTotalHoursWorked() * employee.wage).ToString("C", new CultureInfo("id")), main, brush, 211.25f, 264.85f);

        graph.DrawString(GetLunchCoefficient().ToString(new CultureInfo("id")), main, brush, 135.645f, 281.546f);

        graph.DrawString((GetLunchCoefficient() * Commons.CurrentConfig.lunch_money).ToString("C", new CultureInfo("id")), main, brush, 211.25f, 281.5f);

        graph.DrawString(bpjs_tk.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("id")), main, brush, 211.2415f, 319f);
        graph.DrawString(bpjs_kes.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("id")), main, brush, 211.2415f, 333.175f);
        graph.DrawString(debts.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("id")), main, brush, 211.2415f, 347.35f);
        graph.DrawString(deposits.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("id")), main, brush, 211.2415f, 361.5f);

        graph.DrawString(others_desc, main, brush, 88.77f, 375.7f);
        graph.DrawString(others_amt.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("id")), main, brush, 211.25f, 375.7f);

        graph.DrawString(GetTotalEarnings().ToString("C", new CultureInfo("id")), main, brush, 211.25f, 389.85f);

        graph.DrawString((employee.balance - debts + deposits).ToString("C", new CultureInfo("id")), main, brush, 125.75f, 404f);
    }

    List<PdfPage> list = new List<PdfPage>();
    foreach (PdfPage p in pdf.Pages) list.Add(p);

    return list;
}
```

All it does is draw data over a template and return the pages.

Here is the function calling all the `GetPdfPages()`:

```
private void printAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "PDF Document (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*", FileName = "Print.pdf" };
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;

        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();

        foreach(Slip slip in Commons.CurrentBatch.slips) {
            try {
                List<PdfPage> doc = slip.GetPdfPages(Commons.CurrentBatch.date);
                foreach (PdfPage page in doc) pdf.AddPage(page);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException x) {
                MessageBox.Show("The Template is missing. Please reinstall using the installer", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                Debug.WriteLine(x.Message);
                return;
            } catch (FileLoadException x) {
                MessageBox.Show("The Template is corrupted. Please reinstall using the installer", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                Debug.WriteLine(x.Message);
                return;
            }
        }

        pdf.Save(Path.GetFullPath(dialog.FileName));
    }
```

However, using this method will throw this exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: A PDF document must be opened with PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import to import pages from it.
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPages.ImportExternalPage(PdfPage importPage)
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPages.Insert(Int32 index, PdfPage page)
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument.AddPage(PdfPage page)
   at Project.FormEditor.PrintBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in Project\FormEditor.cs:line 352
```

Note: the problematic line of code is `pdf.AddPage(page);`

Is there a way to reimport those pages again so that they can be added to a `PdfDocument`?

Another way which I would not like to use but I will if necessary is to save all the results of `GetPdfPages()` to a file and reimport them using `PdfReader.Open(path, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import)`.

Comment: You can save to a `MemoryStream` to avoid saving to a file. No MCVE given. `GetPdfPages` returns a list of pages, but temporarily imports the pages to a PdfDocument. If possible, do not add the pages to the document and you are done. Otherwise write to a stream and open that stream for import.

Comment: Yes, `MemoryStream` totally worked! Searching the Internet didn't get me this. Thanks a lot, @Ballyoleidjit!

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" here: you import the pages from a PDF document opened in Import mode and add them to a temporary PDF document. Then you loop through the pages of this temporary document and try to add them to the final document, which leads to the error message.

A simple workaround is saving the temporary PDF document to a `MemoryStream` and opening a new PDF document from that stream in Import mode, thus allowing the pages to be added to a new PDF document.

IMHO it would be a cleaner solution to eliminate the temporary PDF and add the imported PDF pages directly to the destination PDF. It should be a simple change to pass the final `PdfDocument` as a parameter to `GetPdfPages` and have that method add the pages directly to their final destination.